# Android ViewModel and Firebase fetching empty list

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mvvm

I am using a **ViewModel** architecture along with a **Firebase Realtime Database** to manage the data of my app.

**The App Description:**
There is a Splash Activity, Login Activity, Game Activity, and Leaderboard Activity. The complete user data is retrieved once at the splash activity to check if the user has an internet connection on successful retrieval, login activity opens or gets bypassed to Game Activity. The leaderboard activity can be opened from both LoginActivity and GameAcivity.

**The problem:**
Whenever I try to open the leaderboard from GameActivity, I always get an empty list returned. This problem never arises when I open it from LoginActivity however. However, If I ever log in and then change the database data from the firebase console, I do get a non-empty list in Leaderboard.

**What I have tried?:**
Debugging and logging the Repository code, to find that onDataChange() is never called inside LeaderboardActivity when I reach there from GameActivity however ViewModel calls go as expected.

I also tried to retrieve list using **model.getUsers().getValue();** but this returns null.

**Code:**

*GameViewModel.java*

```
public class GameViewModel extends ViewModel implements DataRetrievedInterface {

    private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;
    private GameRepository repository = GameRepository.getInstance(this);

    public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadUsers();
        }
        return users;
    }

    private void loadUsers() {
        repository.retrieveData();
    }

    private void loadUsers(List<User> result) {
        users.setValue(result);
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        List<User> us = users.getValue();
        assert us != null;
        us.add(user);
        repository.addUser(us);
        users.postValue(us);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataRetrieved(List<User> result) {
        loadUsers(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
        repository.removeListener();
    }

    public void updateScore(String userName, Long score) {
        repository.updateScore(userName, score);
    }
}
```

*GameRepository.java*

```
public class GameRepository {

    public final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Users");
    public DataRetrievedInterface retrievedInterface;

    private static GameRepository repository = null;

    ValueEventListener eventListener;

    private GameRepository(DataRetrievedInterface retrievedInterface) {
        this.retrievedInterface = retrievedInterface;
    }

    public static GameRepository getInstance(DataRetrievedInterface retrievedInterface) {
        if(repository==null)
            repository = new GameRepository(retrievedInterface);

        repository.eventListener = (new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    users.add(snapshot1.getValue(User.class));
                }

                retrievedInterface.notifyDataRetrieved(users);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e("Database Error", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return repository;
    }

    public void retrieveData() {
        ref.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
    }

    public void removeListener() {
        ref.removeEventListener(eventListener);
    }

    public void addUser(List<User> user) {
        ref.setValue(user);
    }

    public void updateScore(String userName, Long score) {
// assume temp is a one time listener for updating value in db
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(temp);
    }

}
```

*SplashActivity.java*

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intent;

    GameViewModel model;
    Boolean isDataReady = false;
    Boolean isAnimationDone = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        model = (new ViewModelProvider(this)).get(GameViewModel.class);

        model.getUsers().observe(this, u -> {
            isDataReady = true;
            if(isAnimationDone) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initViewsAndVars() {
        intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    
        intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
        
        if(isDataReady) {
              startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

*GameActivity.java*

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GameStatusInterface {

    GamePlay gamePlay;
    GameViewModel model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        gamePlay = new GamePlay(this, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        btnLeader = findViewById(R.id.btnLeaderGame);

        model = (new ViewModelProvider(this)).get(GameViewModel.class);

        btnLeader.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LeaderboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onGameEnded(Long score) {
        model.updateScore(userName, current + score);
    }

}
```

*LeaderboardActivity.java*

```
public class LeaderboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LeaderboardRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);

        adapter = new LeaderboardRecyclerAdapter(users);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        GameViewModel model = (new ViewModelProvider(this)).get(GameViewModel.class);

        model.getUsers().observe(this, u -> {
            users.clear();
            users.addAll(u);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

    }

}
```

*LoginActivity.java*

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intent;

    GameViewModel model;
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
                SP_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        model = (new ViewModelProvider(this)).get(GameViewModel.class);

        model.getUsers().observe(this, u -> {
            userList = u;
        });

    }

    private void setListeners() {

        ivLeaderboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LeaderboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login();
            }
        });

    }

    private void login() {
// Login Checks Here
        intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);        

    }

}
```

*Assume that the code works for other functionality, have removed the parts that were not necessary for this question.*

Comment: Please include the minimal, runnable code relevant to the issue, not a dump of the entire app for others to try and debug. Most likely, you'll find that an error is generated an the listener is canceled, probably because it is established before authentication finishes resolving.

Comment: @Kato Thanks for suggestion, I have shortened the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually removing the listener attached to FirebaseReference just before the activity is destroyed solves the problem. Earlier the implementation was following ViewModel lifecycle, hence technically a listener was getting attached and subsequently removed, hence empty list.

**Code Changes:**

*GameViewModel.java*

```
public void removeListener() {
    repository.removeListener();
}

@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();
}
```

*XyzActivity.java*

```
model.removeListener();
startActivity(intent);
```